# MethodNotAllowedHttpException on Form Submission Stripe.js

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, stripe-payments

I was experimenting with Stripe JS and got in some issues with this error. Following is my Route View & JS File. When i submit the post, it gives me the following error, MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Route

```
> Route::get('buy', function () {
>     return view('buy'); });
```

JS File

> ```
> $( document ).ready(function(){
>     var StripeBilling = {
>         init: function(){
>             this.form = $('.billing-form');
>             this.submitButton = this.form.find('input[type=submit]');
>
>             var stripeKey = $('meta[name="secret-key"]').attr('content');
>             Stripe.setPublishableKey(stripeKey);
>
>             this.bindEvents();
>         },
>
>         bindEvents: function () {
>             this.form.on('submit', $.proxy(this.sendToken, this));
>         },
>
>         sendToken: function (event) {
>             this.submitButton.val('One Moment');
>
>             Stripe.createToken(this.form, $.proxy(this.stripeResponseHandler, this));
>
>             event.preventDefault();
>
>         },
>
>         stripeResponseHandler: function(status, response){
>             console.log(status, response);
>         }
>     };
>
>     StripeBilling.init();
> })
> ```

Default View

> ```
> @section('content')
>
>     <div class="row">
>         <h1>Buy for $1</h1>
>
>         {!! Form::open(['id' => '#billing-form']) !!}
>           <div class="form-row">
>                 <label>
>                     <span>Card Number:</span>
>                     <input type="text" data-stripe="number">
>                 </label>
>             </div>
>             <div class="form-row">
>                 <label>
>                     <span>CVC:</span>
>                     <input type="text" data-stripe="cvc">
>                 </label>
>             </div>
>             <div class="form-row">
>                 <label>
>                     <span>Expiration:</span>
>                     {!! Form::selectMonth(null , null, ['data-stripe' => 'exp-month']) !!}
>                     {!! Form::selectYear(null, date('Y'),date('Y') + 10, null, ['data-stripe' => 'exp-year'] ) !!}
>                 </label>
>             </div>
>
>                 <div>
>                     {!! Form::submit('submit') !!}
>                 </div>
>         {!! Form::close() !!}
>     </div>
>
> @stop
>
> @section('footer')
>     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
>     <script src="/js/billing.js"></script>
> @stop
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes file you defined the path as a GET request but your form submission is doing a POST request either change your form to submit as a GET request or update your routes so it is a POST request

Comment: Now it works, but it's not receiving any errors neither an object is returned from the api.

Comment: your route code only displays a view, where does it call the create charge api or anything?